# In Prison Break, how is Whip T-Bag's son?

Tags: plot-explanation, prison-break

In Prison Break S02E17, T-Bag admits to Susan that he cannot procreate.
But in Prison Break 5th season, they show that Whip is actually T-Bag's son. How is that possible? Or is that a plot hole?

Comment: Doesn't this depend on **when** T-Bag ceased to be able to procreate?

Comment: Oh! I assumed he wasn't since the beginning :P Good point. Is there any clarification regarding that?

Comment: does he said he can't or he wont? I'm not sure about that scene

Comment: He says he cannot procreate. I'm sure because I watched it again now :)

Comment: @Snow T-Bag also says that he is the last in the line of Bagwells, the tail-end of a corrupted breed. Then he says he cannot procreate. I think that implies he was never ever able to procreate.

Comment: Well, it certainly implies that *he doesn't think he can procreate.*  I don't recall him citing his source on knowing that, though, and even doctors can be wrong sometimes.  The existence of a son would seem to contradict his belief.